# Google Play Installer_referrer issue

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play, referrer

So, I risk doubling upon doubling for this issue, and people stoning me for it.. :/

Can anyone shed some light about how the market web interface doesn't "ignite" the 
`com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` broadcast receiver.

Is there an official Google statement on this?

What's the verdict?

(btw, as opposed to the web market version, installing my app from the market app does come with a referrer string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known issues, point 2:

"Google Play Campaign Tracking does not currently support web-to-device installs initiated from the web Play Store."

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns#known-issues